# Scriptkit toast notification

Tags: toast

New to scriptkit and love it. I have a script which will make a web request and I'd like the UI to be 'non-blocking' - i.e. the scriptkit window to be hidden, but get a notification when the task is completed successfully.

I can't see anything similar in the samples. Anyone know of a way to achieve this?